# asp.net multiple gridviews - not display data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridView and i want display data from two DataTables. There is my GridViews code in aspx file :

```
 <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvSource" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="drag_drop_grid GridSrc" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Miejsca (wybór)</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNazwa" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nazwa") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="IDVal" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvDest" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No data to display" CssClass="drag_drop_grid GridDest" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Miejsca (należące do wycieczki)</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNazwa"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nazwa") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="IDVal" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is my Code-Behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                recID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                if (recID > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Nazwa", typeof(string)) });
                    dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Nazwa", typeof(string)) });

                    Miejsca ms = new Miejsca();
                    Hashtable hs = new Hashtable();


                    foreach (var lst in ms.PobierzMiejscaLista(hs))
                    {

                        dt.Rows.Add(lst.Id , lst.Nazwa);
                    }

                    gvSource.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                    gvSource.DataSource = dt;

                    gvSource.DataBind();

                   dt.Rows.Clear();
                   dt.Rows.Add();

                    Wycieczka w = (new Wycieczki()).PobierzWycieczke(recID);



                    foreach (var lst in w.Miejsca)
                    {
                        Miejsce tempM = (new Miejsca()).PobierzMiejsce(lst.Id_Miejsce.Id);
                        dt2.Rows.Add(tempM.Id, tempM.Nazwa);

                    }
                    int ilosc = dt2.Rows.Count;
                    //gvDest.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                    gvDest.DataSource = dt2;
                    gvDest.DataBind();


                    //Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "TablicaMiejsc", "loadPlacesIntoTrip("+recID+");", true);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Nazwa") });


                Miejsca ms = new Miejsca();
                Hashtable hs = new Hashtable();

                foreach (var lst in ms.PobierzMiejscaLista(hs))
                {
                    //listMiejsc.Add(lst);
                    dt.Rows.Add(lst.Id, lst.Nazwa);
                }

                gvSource.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                gvSource.DataSource = dt;

                gvSource.DataBind();

                dt.Rows.Clear();
                dt.Rows.Add();
                gvDest.DataSource = new List<String>();
                gvDest.DataBind();
                recID = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

And i don't know why but only one GridView (gvSource) display data.
Second GridView (gvDest) not display data.
When i debug code i see both DataTables have data. Both GridView DataSources have data too. But only one GridView display data.

I use Nhibernate to lazy load (w.Miejsca) collection and get objects like "Miejsce" or "Wycieczka" from database. Also I use JQuery and JQuery UI to make sortable GridViews.

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.
I hope you can help me :)

**UPDATE**

Finally I found what is responsible for this situation.
Because of my stupidity i lost a lot of time :)

This line of code is removed the items from GridView:

```
$("[id*=gvDest] tr:not(tr:first-child)").remove();
```

Thank you for your advice.
The problem was solved.

Comment: I'm not an expert on datatables, but why are you clearing your dt.Rows?

Comment: I just forgot to remove this code. But i test it without this code and it no help.

Comment: the only part of your code that might not show data is this line: gvDest.DataSource = new List<String>(); You are putting an empty list as the datasource?

Comment: yes but only when i have recid = 0. But my problem is when i have recid > 0 and i want to show data in gridview. May i don't know correctly how works Eval or DataTable and i doing something wrong :(.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove ClientIDMode="Static" from second grid view and check it.